# Are our moderators legal?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We know there is a famous Drash of "Som Tasim Alecha Melech". From here we have several Diyukim:

1. Melech velo Malka - How do we have a woman mod?
2. Melech (singular) - we can only have one mod. How do we have 3?

If they are not legal, is there *Dina D'Malchusa* regarding stackexchange? Do I have to obey them?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: But how did you know I was a woman???

Comment: @DoubleAA https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27069

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A moderator is more of a shoter than a melekh, from D'varim 16:18:

> שֹׁפְטִ֣ים וְשֹֽׁטְרִ֗ים תִּֽתֶּן־לְךָ֙ בְּכָל־שְׁעָרֶ֔יךָ

This is clearly plural.

Comment: Clearly, then, [women may also serve as mods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deborah).

Comment: This answer could be improved with some explanation of the difference between Melech and Shoter and how mods are more like the latter. @SethJ, Devora was a shofetet, not a shoteret. Are you saying that the latter follows from the former by kal vechomer, by juxtaposition (hekesh) in the verse in Devarim, or by some other mechanism?

Comment: @IsaacMoses You're right, I didn't read the answer carefully enough. I was focused on the Pasuk. However, I believe the mods also serve as Shofetim.

Answer (score 16):

According to Stack Exchange, moderators are [custodians and human exception-handlers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).  When's the last time you saw a king doing his own custodial work?

Comment: *I know I'm not supposed to break character, but I'm literally cracking up at this question!*

Comment: I guess the mod job would include spackling cracks, too.  I'll be right over!

Comment: @Aarthi For full effect: drash==exposition, som tasim alecha melech==the opening of [Deuteronomy 17:15](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0517.htm#15), melech velo malka == king but not queen, melech == king (not kings), dina demalchusa == follow the laws of the land when they don't contradict halacha.

Comment: @Aarthi Hey cool, I can upvote your comment twice! Once on meta and once here. :)